# How to make time delay in last @keyframe CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have animation on path. This is my css code:

```
#target {
  -webkit-animation: myPathX 1.5s infinite ;
  -moz-animation: myPathX 1.5s infinite ;
  -ms-animation: myPathX 1.5s infinite ;
  -o-animation: myPathX 1.5s infinite ;
  animation: myPathX 1.5s infinite ;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  -moz-animation-delay:10s;


}

#target > * {
  -webkit-animation: myPathY 1.5s infinite ;
  -moz-animation: myPathY 1.5s infinite ;
  -ms-animation: myPathY 1.5s infinite ;
  -o-animation: myPathY 1.5s infinite ;
  animation: myPathY 1.5s infinite ;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
```

-moz-animation-delay:10s;
I want to make delay in last @keyframe ? How i can make this ? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try: `animation-delay: 2s;`.